# Weak convergence in the Skorohod space $D([0, T])$ $\forall T$ implies Weak convergence in $D([0, \infty))$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

Assume that $Z_n$ are random variables taking value in the Skorohod space $D([0, \infty),Y)$ (endowed with its usual Skorohod topology) of right-continuous functions $[0, \infty) \to Y$, where $Y$ is a real separable Banach space. Assume that $\forall T>0$, $Z_n$ converge weakly (in distribution) to $Z$ in the space $D([0, T],Y)$, where $Z$ is a random variable defined on $D([0, \infty),Y)$. Does it hold that $Z_n$ converge weakly to $Z$ in the space $D([0, \infty),Y)$? What about if an assumption is made on $Z$, for example $Z$ is a constant random variable or $Z$ is continuous, i.e. it belongs to $C([0, \infty),Y)$.

Comment: the metric on $D[0,\infty)$ is something like $\int_0^\infty e^{-t} \sup_{u \leq t} ||z_n(u)-z(u)||dt$. Therefore if you take your example of a continuous function equals to 1 on $[0,n]$ and 0 after $n+1$, then we have convergence to $z=1$ on $D[0,T]$ and also on $D[0,\infty)$ because $d(z_n,z)\leq e^{-n} \to 0$.

Comment: How can you be sure that this metric is well-defined (for example with $Y=\mathbb R$ and $z(u):=e^{u^2}$)? Do you have to assume boundedness?

Comment: Good remark. The answer is because I did not give you the exact metric, I said "something like", to have the spirit. The real metric is: $d(z_n,z)= \inf_{\lambda \in \Lambda} [\gamma(\lambda) \vee \int_0^\infty e^{-t} [1 \wedge (\sup_{u \leq t} ||z_n(t)-z(\lambda(t))||)]dt ]$, where $\Lambda$ is the set of strictly increasing lipschitz continuous functions, with $\lambda(0)=0$.

Comment: so the answer to your question is that the $\sup$ is bounded by 1 inside the integral.

Comment: I see. So in this context, convergence of finite-dimensional distributions is not a problem. Have you checked tightness criterion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We shall use Theorem 4.2. in Billingsley's book *Convergence of probability measures* (1968):

> **Theorem.** Let $\left(S,d\right)$ be a separable metric space and for $u,n\in\mathbb N$, $Y_n,X_{u,n}$ and $X$ are $S$-valued random variables defined on a common probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu\right)$. We assume that
>
> 1. for all $u\in\mathbb N$, $X_{un}\to X_u$ in distribution as $n\to \infty$;
> 2. $X_u\to X$ in distribution as $u\to \infty$, and
> 3. for each $\varepsilon\gt 0$, $\lim_{u\to \infty}\limsup_{n\to \infty}\mu\left\{d\left(X_{u,n},Y_n\right)\gt\varepsilon\right\}=0$.
>
> Then $Y_n\to X$ in distribution as $n\to \infty$.

The proof uses portmanteau theorem: we take $F\subset S$ a closed set, and we define $F_\varepsilon:=\{x,d(x,F)\leqslant\varepsilon\}$, where $d(x,F):=\inf\left\{d(x,y),y\in F\right\}$. Then
$$\mu\{Y_n\in F\}\leqslant \mu\{X_{u,n}\in F_\varepsilon\}+\mu\{d(X_{u,n},Y_n)\gt\varepsilon\},$$
hence taking the $\limsup_{n\to \infty}$,
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\mu\{Y_n\in F\}\leqslant \mu\{X_u\in F_\varepsilon\}+\limsup_{n\to \infty}\mu\{d(X_{u,n},Y_n)\gt\varepsilon\}.$$
Taking now $\limsup_{u\to \infty}$, we get in view of 3.
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\mu\{Y_n\in F\}\leqslant \limsup_{u\to \infty}\mu\{X_u\in F_\varepsilon\}\leqslant \mu\{X\in F_\varepsilon\},$$
and we conclude, using the fact that $\bigcap_{\varepsilon >0}F_\varepsilon=F$, $F$ begin closed.

Now, we shall use this result to prove that if $Z_n\to Z$ in distribution in $D[0,T]$ for all $T$, then actually the convergence takes place in $D[0,\infty)$. We define
$$X_{u,n}(t,\omega):=Z_n(t,\omega)\chi_{[0,u)}(t)$$
$$Y_n:=Z_n; \quad X:=Z.$$
We check the third condition. Notice that by definition of the metric on $D[0,\infty)$, we have that
$$d(X_{u,n},Y_n)\leqslant \int_u^{\infty}e^{-t}\mathrm dt,$$
because we can bound the distance restricting the infimum to the increasing Lipschitz maps $\gamma$ for which $\gamma(s)=s$ for $0\leqslant s\leqslant u$.

Comment: Thought I would miss something. Thanks for the quick response. [I've got a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019020/convergence-of-discret-time-markov-chain-to-feller-processes) where a theorem similar the one you've proven here is needed. Maybe you can help there too.

Comment: How did you obtain $\limsup_{n\to \infty}\mu\{Y_n\in F\}\leqslant \mu\{X\in F_\varepsilon\}$? It seems like that you've used that $\lim_{u\to\infty}\mu\{X_u\in F_\varepsilon\}\leqslant \mu\{X\in F_\varepsilon\}$, but doesn't the Portmanteau theorem only yield $\limsup_{u\to\infty}\mu\{X_u\in F_\varepsilon\}\leqslant \mu\{X\in F_\varepsilon\}$?

Comment: Then we only need $\limsup_{u\to\infty}$ in 3., right?

Comment: This would actually be equivalent, since a sequence of non-negative numbers converges to $0$ if and only if its $\limsup$ is zero.

Comment: Any reason you've excluded $u$ in the interval in the definition of $X_{u,n}(t,\omega):=Z_n(t,\omega)\chi_{[0,u)}(t)$? I'm actually not sure what you've proved in the end. I guess your initial assumption was $Z_n\to Z$ weakly in $D([0,T])$ for all $T>0$. Strictly speaking, we deal with different separable metric spaces and hence we cannot directly apply the theorem. It seems like that you've assumed that $X_{un}\to 1_{[0,\:u]}Z$ weakly in $D([0,\infty))$ as $n\to\infty$, but how do you know that? This seems to be an invocation of the claim we're actually trying to prove.

Comment: I would be really grateful if you could shortly tell me whether you're not responding cause the question is trivial or you need to think about it (no offense intended).

Comment: Are you not answering cause you think the question is trivial or don't you remember what your idea was? Would be great if you could give any feedback.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I need a little bit more time to think about it.

Comment: I'd still be interested in a response.