# Convergence of discrete-time Markov chain to Feller processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Feller process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $(h_d)_{d\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ with $$h_d\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
- $\left(Y^{(d)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a time-homogeneous Markov chain on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$X^{(d)}_t:=Y^{(d)}_{\lfloor\frac t{h_d}\rfloor}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for $d\in\mathbb N$
- $N$ be a Poisson process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with parameter $1$ independent of $Y^{(d)}$ for all $d\in\mathbb N$ and $$N^{(d)}_t:=N_{\frac t{h_d}}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ as well as $$\tilde X^{(d)}_t:=Y^{(d)}_{N^{(d)}_t}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for $d\in\mathbb N$

Note that $N^{(d)}$ is a Poisson process with parameter $h_d^{-1}$ for all $d\in\mathbb N$.

> How can we show that (in probability with respect to the Skorohod topology) $X^{(d)}\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}X$ iff $\tilde X^{(d)}\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}X$?

In the book of Kallenberg, the author is mentioning that the claim follows from the following two theorems:

[image: kallenberg]

I don't get how we need to apply them. Clearly, for fixed $t\ge0$, we can consider $$\frac1d\sum_{i=1}^d\left(N^{(i)}_t-N^{(i-1)}_t\right)$$ with $N^{(0)}_t:=0$. However, while independent, the $N^{(i)}_t-N^{(i-1)}$ are *not* identically distributed ...

---

If it's hard to prove in the general setting, it's okay for me to assume $h_d^{-1}=d$ for all $d\in\mathbb N$. In that case, the strong law of large numbers yields $$\sup_{t\in[0,\:T]}\left|\frac1d N^{(d)}_t-t\right|\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }T>0\tag1.$$ Now, let $\tau^{(d)}_0:=0$, $$\tau_n^{(d)}:=\inf\left\{t>\tau^{(d)}_{n-1}:N^{(d)}_t-N^{(d)}_{\tau^{(d)}_{n-1}}>0\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }d\in\mathbb N$$ and $$\lambda^{(d)}_t:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty1_{\left[\frac nd,\:\frac{n+1}d\right)}(t)\left(\tau^{(d)}_n+(dt-n)\left(\tau^{(d)}_{n+1}-\tau^{(d)}_n\right)\right)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for $d\in\mathbb N$. Moreoverr, let $T>0$ and $\rho_T$ denote the metric inducing the Skorohod $J_1$-topology on the space of càdlàg functions $[0,T]\to\mathbb R$. We should obtain $$\rho_T\left(X^{(d)},\tilde X^{(d)}\right)\le\sup_{t\in[0,\:T]}\left|\lambda^{(d)}_t-t\right|+\sup_{t\in[0,\:T]}\left|X^{(d)}_t-\tilde X^{(d)}_{\lambda^{(d)}_t}\right|\tag2,$$ where the last term should be $0$. So, if we could show that the first term converges in probability to $0$ as $d\to\infty$, [we should be able to conclude](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470809/weak-convergence-in-the-skorohod-space-d0-t-forall-t-implies-weak-conv#475011) (since $T$ was arbitrary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** The consequences of Theorem 1, below, have been more neatly stated in Corollary 1 and Lemma 1. To Lemma 1, I am adding an extra-assumption: the limit process $X$ has continuous sample-paths, almost surely.

---

I will build from what you proposed and I may repeat some passages to make sure everything is in place.

> **Theorem 1.** $\mathbb{P}\left(\rho_{T}\left(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)}\right)>\epsilon\right)\overset{d\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow 0$, for any $\epsilon>0$.

Theorem 1 will imply Corollary 1 and Lemma 1 further ahead.

---

**Preliminary Remarks.** I am assuming that $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$ is endowed with the (incomplete) metric $\rho_{T}(X,Y)=\inf_{\lambda\in \Lambda_T}\left\{\left|\left|\lambda-{\sf id}\right|\right|\vee \left|\left|X\circ\lambda-Y\right|\right|\right\}$, where

$\Lambda_T\overset{\Delta}=\left\{\lambda\,:\,\left[0,T\right]\rightarrow \left[0,T\right]\,:\,\lambda\mbox{ is bijective, continuous and }\lambda(0)=0,\,\lambda(T)=T\right\}$;

${\sf id}$ is the identity map from $\left[0,T\right]$ onto itself; and we have defined

$\left|\left|X\right|\right|=\sup_{t\in\left[0,T\right]} \left|X(t)\right|$

as the $\sup$ norm on the interval $\left[0,T\right]$.

Note that for a particular $\lambda\in\Lambda_T$, we have $\rho_T(X,Y)\leq\left|\left|\lambda-{\sf id}\right|\right|+\left|\left|X\circ\lambda-Y\right|\right|$ (as pointed out in your equation (2)).

---

**Proof to Theorem 1.** We need to slightly correct your $\lambda^{(d)}_t$ so it belongs to $\Lambda_T$ (almost surely), since in your case $\lambda_T^{(d)}\neq T$ almost surely (and we need $\lambda(0)=0$ and $\lambda(T)=T$). Define $n^{\star}\overset{\Delta}=\min\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}_0\,:\,\tau_{n+1}^{(d)}> T\right\}$, -- note that $n^{\star}(\omega)=N_{T}^{(d)}(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, -- and let us redefine your $\lambda_t^{(d)}$ rather as

$\lambda_t^{(d)}\overset{\Delta}=\sum_{n=0}^{n^{\star}}1_{\left.\left[\frac{n}{d},\frac{n+1}{d}\right.\right)}(t)\left(\tau_n^{(d)}+\left(dt-n\right)\left(\tau_{n+1}^{(d)}-\tau_n^{(d)}\right)\right)+1_{\left[\left.\frac{n^{\star}}{d},T\right]\right.}(t)\left(\tau_{n^{\star}}^{(d)}+(\frac{dt-n^{\star}}{Td-n^{\star}})\left(T-\tau_{n^{\star}}^{(d)}\right)\right)$

Now we have that $\lambda^{(d)}_t\in \Lambda_T$ for all $d$, almost surely. Note, in particular, that $\lambda^{(d)}_T=T$.

We have that

$\rho_T(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)})\leq\left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}-{\sf id}\right|\right|+\left|\left|\overline{X}^{(d)}\circ\lambda^{(d)}-X^{(d)}\right|\right|=\left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}-{\sf id}\right|\right|.\tag{1}$

Note that without the correction on $\lambda^{(d)}_t$ the second term on the left-hand side of the identity above would not be zero.

Now, we observe that

$\left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}-{\sf id}\right|\right|=\frac{1}{d}\sup_{k\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N_{T}^{(d)}\right\}}\left|\tau_k-k\right|=\sup_{t\in\left[0,\tau_{n^{\star}}\right]}\frac{1}{d}\left|N_{t}^{(d)}-td\right|\leq \sup_{t\in\left[0,T\right]}\frac{1}{d}\left|N_{t}^{(d)}-td\right|$,

where for the first identity above: i) without loss of optimality, we can restrict attention to the jump moments plus the final moment $T$; (ii) in the final moment $T$, $\lambda_T^{(d)}-T=0$, thus we can restrict attention to the jumps within the interval $\left[0,T\right]$ and ignore the moment $T$. Observe that without the correction on $\lambda_t^{(d)}$ the first identity would not hold true (and the devised upper-bound above would not follow).

Note that $N^{(d)}_t-td$ is a martingale with $N_{T}^{(d)}-Td\in L_2$ and from Doob's inequality

$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{t\in\left[0,T\right]}\left|\lambda_{t}^{(d)}-t\right|>\epsilon\right)\leq\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{t\in\left[0,T\right]}\frac{1}{d}\left|N_{t}^{(d)}-td\right|>\epsilon\right)\leq \frac{E\left[\left(N_{T}^{(d)}-Td\right)^2\right]}{d^2\epsilon^2}=\frac{Td}{d^2 \epsilon^2}=\frac{T}{d\epsilon}\overset{d\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow 0$.

From the bound (1), we have $\rho_T(\overline{X}^{(d)}(\omega),X^{(d)}(\omega))>\epsilon \Rightarrow \left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}(\omega)-{\sf id}\right|\right|>\epsilon$ and thus,

$\mathbb{P}\left(\rho_T(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)})>\epsilon\right)\leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}-{\sf id}\right|\right|>\epsilon\right)\overset{d\rightarrow\infty}\longrightarrow 0$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

---

> **Corollary 1.[Convergence in probability]** For every $T>0$, we have
>
> $\mathbb{P}\left(\rho_T\left(X^{(d)},X\right)>\epsilon\right)\longrightarrow 0$ for all $\epsilon>0$ $\Leftrightarrow \mathbb{P}\left(\rho_T\left(\overline{X}^{(d)},X\right)>\epsilon\right)\longrightarrow 0$ for all $\epsilon>0$, i.e.,
> $X^{(d)}\rightarrow X$ in probability w.r.t. $\left(\rho_T, D_{\left[0,T\right]}\right)$ if and only if $\overline{X}^{(d)}\rightarrow X$ in probability w.r.t. $\left(\rho_T, D_{\left[0,T\right]}\right)$.

**Proof to Corollary 1.** Obvious from Theorem 1. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

---

In what follows, $\rho^{o}_T$ is a metric that is topologically equivalent to $\rho_T$, i.e., it induces the same (Skorokhod) topology on $D_{\left[0,T\right)}$, except that the metric space $\left(\rho^{o}_T,D_{\left[0,T\right)}\right)$ is complete. $\rho^{o}$ is a metric built upon $\left\{\rho^{o}_T\right\}_{T=1}^{\infty}$ and inducing the Skorokhod topology on $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$, with $\left(\rho^{o},D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}\right)$ complete. Their explicit characterizations can be abstracted in what follows, but can be found in equations (16.4) for $\rho^{o}$ and (12.16) for $\rho^{o}_{T}$ of Patrick Billingsley "Convergence of Probability Measures".

> **Lemma 1.[Weak convergence]** If $\mathbb{P}\left(X\in\mathcal{C}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}\right)=1$, then $X^{(d)}\longrightarrow X$ weakly w.r.t the Skorokhod topology in $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$ if and only if  $\overline{X}^{(d)}\longrightarrow X$ weakly w.r.t. the Skorokhod topology in $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$.

**Proof to Lemma 1.** Let $X^{(d)}\longrightarrow X$ weakly in $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$. Then, in view of the Skorokhod Representation Theorem, Theorem 6.7 in Billingsley, we have $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}\equiv X^{(d)}$ and $\widetilde{X}\equiv X$, where $\equiv$ stands for equal in distribution, so that $\rho^{o}(\widetilde{X}^{(d)}(\omega),\widetilde{X}(\omega))\rightarrow 0$, for all $\omega\in \Omega$. Note that $\mathbb{P}\left(\widetilde{X}\in\mathcal{C}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X\in\mathcal{C}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}\right)=1$ and from Theorem 16.2, Billingsley, we have that $\rho^{o}_{T}(\widetilde{X}^{(d)},\widetilde{X})\rightarrow 0$ for all $T>0$, almost surely. This further implies that $X^{(d)}\longrightarrow X$ weakly with respect to $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$. Now we resort to Theorem 4.28 referred to in the question and to Theorem 1. Let $\epsilon,\delta>0$ and choose $d$ large enough so that $\mathbb{P}\left(\rho_{T}\left(X^{(d)},\overline{X}^{(d)}\right)\leq\epsilon\right)\geq 1-\delta$, then $E\left[\rho_{T}\left(X^{(d)},\overline{X}^{(d)}\right)\wedge 1\right]\leq \epsilon+\delta$, and thus we have $\limsup_{d\rightarrow\infty} E\left[\rho_{T}\left(X^{(d)},\overline{X}^{(d)}\right)\wedge 1\right]=0$. This implies that $\overline{X}^{(d)}\longrightarrow X$ weakly with respect to $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$ in light of Theorem 4.28. This convergence holds for all $T$. With the same Skorokhod representation+Theorem 16.2, we can conclude that $\overline{X}^{(d)}\longrightarrow X$ converges weakly with respect to the Skorokhod topology in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: I will check this answer soon. At the moment, I'm a bit struggling with the usual definitions. If we consider càdlàg functions $[0,t]\to E$, where $(E,d)$ is a metric space, is the following the (incomplete) metric which induces the so-called $J_1$-topology?: Let $\Lambda:=\left\{\lambda:[0,t]\to[0,t]\mid\lambda\text{ is bijective and continuous with }\lambda(0)=0\right\}$ (I guess $λ(0)=0$ is to ensure that $λ$ is increasing (and not decreasing)). Then the $J_1$-metric should be $$\sigma(x,y):=\inf_{λ\in\Lambda}\left(\sup_{s\le t}|λ(s)-s|+\sup_{s\le t}d(x(s),(y\circλ)(s))\right),$$ right?

Comment: For the metric, I am resorting to Patrick Billingsley's "Convergence of Probability Measures" definition. What you wrote is consistent with the definition I am using, but for the extra condition $\lambda(t)=t$. This is relevant. One (maybe superficial) reason why this is relevant is that the metric is devised to measure distances between points in $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$. If you relax the constraints $\lambda(0)=0$ and $\lambda(t)=t$, you may be running outside the domain of one of the functions. The goal of the abscissa-wiggling function $\lambda$ is (to be continued)

Comment: to lip the following undesired fact. Let $f(t)=1_{t\in\left[\left.1,\infty\right)\right.}$ and $f_n(t)=1_{t\in\left[\left.1+1/n,\infty\right)\right.}$. These are cadlag functions. $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ w.r.t. the $\sup$-norm, but it converges with respect to the above Skorokhod metric. This is because of the extra wiggling $\lambda$. Another reason why it is important to insist on $\lambda(T)=T$ (this is more related to your problem), it is because, if otherwise, the second term in your equation (2) would be no longer zero (and we would have a serious issue).

Comment: I've taken a look into Billingsley's book, but it seems like he's only considering real-valued càdlàg functions. Moreover, he's defining $\Lambda$ to be the set of increasing continuous functions mapping $[0,1]$ onto itself. That should be consistent with my definition. Any continuous function from a closed interval to another closed interval is bijective if and only if it is strictly monotone. That's why in my definition I need to explicitly require $\lambda(0)=0$ (since this yields that $\lambda$ is (strictly) increasing instead of decreasing). Am I missing something?

Comment: That is all correct. In your previous comment, unless I missed something, you missed reinforcing that $\lambda(t)=t$. I just tried to explain why this latter is important. I will also update the answer with the definition of $\Lambda$ as soon as possible.

Comment: The condition $\lambda(T)=T$ is implicit in your first comment -- I missed that.

Comment: Do you know a reference where the Skorohod spaces of functions $[0,t]\to E$ and $[0,\infty)\to E$ for arbitrary metric spaces $E$ are considered?

Comment: "Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence" by Ethier and Kurtz is not purely dedicated to Skorokhod spaces, but it explores the Skorokhod space with underlying $E$ separable and per times complete.

Comment: Yes, but it only considers functions on $[0,\infty)$ where the metric is slightly more complicated.

Comment: I'm a bit struggling with your answer. You say that it's sufficient to show $\mathbb{P}\left(\rho_{T}\left(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)}\right)>\epsilon\right)\overset{d\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow 0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ and $T>0$. That is, it's sufficient to show convergence in probability on each of the Skorohod spaces $D([0,T]$ for all $T>0$. But is this really true? [Here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~serik/WeakConv/C-space.pdf) in Example 9.1 on page 55, it is explicitly remarked that convergence in $D([0,T])$ for all $T>0$ is not equivalent to convergence in $D([0,\infty))$.

Comment: Actually, I think that convergence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ to $x$ in $D([0,\infty))$ is equivalent to that for each $T>0$ there is a $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\Lambda_T$ with $\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}|\lambda_n(s)-s|\vee\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}|x_n(\lambda_n(s))-x(s)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. (And you are doing the analogue for convergence in probability of this in your proof).

Comment: Regarding your first question about the reference, you also have Billingsley. Regarding the proof, we have proved that the Theorem in your question holds in probability w.r.t. the topology $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$ for any $T>0$ (I thought that was your question). On one hand, this does not readily imply convergence in probability for $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$. On the other hand, this implies **weak convergence** w.r.t. $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$ (to be continued)

Comment: and this latter comes from the Theorem 4.28 that you pointed in the post (which is a Theorem about weak convergence on $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$). I will include this part in the answer as soon as possible. So to sum up: with the proof in the answer above, we have convergence in probability w.r.t. $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$ for all $T>0$, and weak convergence w.r.t. $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$ (this latter from Theorem 4.28, and I will include soon). If we insist on convergence in probability over $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$, then we have to think about it.

Comment: (a) Actually, I've made a mistake in phrasing my question. I've confused convergence in probability with convergence in distribution. I'm interested in convergence in distribution only. (b) Do you agree with my equivalent description of convergence in $D([0,\infty))$ in my comment above? If so, your proof shows convergence in probability (and hence in distribution) on every subspace $D([0,t])$. Shouldn't this immediately yield convergence in distribution (or even in probability) on $D([0,\infty))$ by part (a) of this comment? Even without Theorem 4.28.

Comment: (c) your identity $n^\ast=N_T^{(d)}$ holds only almost surely, right? (d) Your proof should still hold for the more general sequence $(h_d)_{d\in\mathbb N}$, right?

Comment: (b) your characterization is correct (and in fact, I think you can find it on Billingsley, as well). But no, it does not transfer to probability/weak convergence right away and I can show you a counter-example (I can detail/explain it better tomorrow): let $X_N$ be a sequence of (real-valued) stochastic processes that converge, say almost surely, to $1$ over any compact interval $\left[0,T\right]$. For each process $X_N$, imagine that there is a hitting time $T_N$ to hit zero, i.e., $X_N(t)=1-1/N$ for all $t\leq T_N$ and $X_N(t)=0$ for $t\geq T_N$, with $T_N\rightarrow \infty$ (to continue)

Comment: with $T_N\rightarrow \infty$, almost surely. In this case, we do not have that $X_N$ converges in probability to $1$ w.r.t. $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$, even though it converges in probability w.r.t. $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$ for all $T$. That is the difference between your statement considering a deterministic sequence and a statement of convergence in probability with a random sequence. (c) yes, this is just to exclude the events where the last jump takes place at $T$, which happens with probability zero. (d) it does, we just need to replace $d$ by $h_d^{-1}$ in (to continue)

Comment: in the proper places, but this does not affect any convergence. I will do the edits.

Comment: for all $T>0$, does not imply convergence in probability on $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$.

Comment: Just a correction to what I said about (b): you need to have $\sup_{s\in\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}\left|\lambda_n(s)-s\right|\vee \sup_{s\in\left[0,t\right]}\left|x_n(\lambda_n(s))-x(s)\right|$, where the first $\sup$ runs over $\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.$ -- this characterization is in Billingsley Theorem 16.1.

Comment: Regarding your characterization (without running the first $\sup$ over $\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.$) I am not sure it implies convergence in $D_{\left[\left.0,\infty\right)\right.}$, I have to think. In fact, the example that I showed above is not a counter-example to your characterization.

Comment: Take a look at Ethier/Kurz [Proposition 5.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=zvE9RFouKoMC&pg=PA121&dq=%22ethier%22+%225.6+theorem%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjaqfywnu3gAhVCEVAKHXvXARcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22ethier%22%20%225.6%20theorem%22&f=true) (you need to scroll two pages up). (5.7) is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{0\le t\le T}|\lambda_n(t)-t|=0$ for all $T>0$.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The issue in your characterization is that you require $\lambda_n\in \Lambda_T$ for all $T$, whereas you have in both Ethier and Billingsley $\lambda_n\in \Lambda$, a sequence of continuous bijections from $\left[0,\infty\right)$. That is what I am not confident about -- but, perhaps I am missing something. Also, as I referred before, the sequence $X_N$ that I mentioned is not a counter-example to your characterization.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I guess Ethier is writing $\lambda_n\in\Lambda$ since he has not defined the sets $\Lambda_T$. And he is writing that the $\lambda_n$ may depend on $T$ and obviously the property they're required to admit does depend on their definition on $[0,T]$ only.

Comment: Indeed, your characterization implies convergence in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ (and vice-versa) if we impose that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{s\in\left[0,T\right]}\left|\lambda^{T}_n(s)-s\right|\vee \sup_{s\in\left[0,T\right]}\left|x_n(\lambda^{T}_n(s))-x(s)\right|=0$ holds for all $T$ continuity-point of the limit process $X$, with $\lambda^{T}_n\in\Lambda_T$. The way, that I could conceive of, to use this fact to finish the proof is via Skorokhod's representation theorem. But, to avoid problems of continuity of the limit process, I assumed $X$ simply almost sure continuous.

Comment: Just one more technical subtlety: How do you obtain $n^\ast=N^{(d)}_T$ (almost surely, I guess)? Do you assume that $N$ is càdlàg for it?

Comment: $n^{\star}$ is defined as the last jump of $N^{(d)}_T$ that occurs within the compact interval $\left[0,T\right]$, i.e., equivalently we have that $\tau_{n^{\star}}(\omega)\leq T$ and $\tau_{n^{\star}+1}(\omega)>T$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$. This comes from the definition. Now, certain realizations $\omega\in\Omega$ are so that the last jump occurs exactly at $T$, i.e., $\tau_{n^{\star}}=T$. For these realizations, we have $n^{\star}(\omega)=N^{(d)}_T+1$ as $N^{(d)}_T$ only counts the jumps within $\left[0,T\right)$. But this set of realizations has probability measure zero.

Comment: The set of realizations where a Poisson jumps at a fixed instant $T$ has probability measure zero zero. Are you asking why that is the case?

Comment: Intuitively, everything is clear to me. But I'm a bit struggling at how we need to define the jumping times of $N$. Most often, the $n$th jump is defined to be $\sigma_n:=\inf\left\{t>\sigma_{n-1}:\Delta N_t>0\right\}$ ($\sigma_0:=0$). However, that's only well-defined if $N$ has left limits. One could alternatively define $\varsigma_n:=\inf\left\{t>\varsigma_{n-1}:N_t-N_{\varsigma_{n-1}}\right\}$ ($\varsigma_0:=0$), but I'm not sure if both are actually the same (when $N$ has left limits)$.

Comment: Can you write down how exactly you are defining $\Delta N_t$?

Comment: If you are defining as $\Delta N_t:=\lim_{s\rightarrow t^{-}} N_t-N_s$, then the definition that you wrote above is not correct as it gives $\sigma_{n-1}$, since $N_t$ is right-continuous and constant almost everywhere.

Comment: A common definition that is close to yours is: $\sigma_n:=\inf\left\{t>\sigma_{n-1}\,:\, N_t-N_{\sigma_{n-1}}>0\right\}$, which is equivalent to the one I wrote in the proof.

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is a regulated process, $\Delta X_t:=X_{t+}-X_{t-}$. I'm not sure if you got me right. I didn't mean that $\sigma_n$ is your $n^\ast$ (but I'm not sure if you thought that I mean this). Moreover, your $\sigma_n$ is precisely my $\varsigma_n$ (besides that I've mistakenly forgot the $>0$ behind $N_t-N_{\varsigma_{n-1}}$). Shouldn't we've got $\sigma_n=\varsigma_n$ surely (the $\sigma_n$ in my previous comment)?

Comment: In any case, this requires that our Poisson process is càdlàg. I would ask whether equivalent stopping times can be defined even without this assumption, but I remember that given any Poisson process we can always find a right-continuous (or even càdlàg?) modification. Do you have a reference for this at hand?

Comment: Yes, we need (or it is sufficient to have) right-continuity. And in fact, there are several equivalent definitions for a Poisson (point) process. All of them imply that there is a c\`adl\`ag modification of the process and that is what we call Poisson process. Check, e.g., Theorem 3.9 of https://books.google.ch/books?id=8Nzn51YTbX4C&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=cadlag+modification+poisson+process&source=bl&ots=CA-GBmw5wo&sig=ACfU3U1AdA7_plAiiSiPx1P9Nay1t9wK5w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ04vg5_fgAhWsxcQBHa_XDKw4ChDoATAEegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=cadlag%20modification%20poisson%20process&f=false

Comment: Could you elaborate on our confusion with the stopping times? I'm still not sure what you've meant in your previous comment.

Comment: There is no confusion regarding the stopping times: either the definition that I wrote in my second to last comment or the one I use in the proof are Ok and equivalent. Underlying this, is the fact that the Poisson process $N_t$ is right-continuous. But, indeed, Poisson processes are c\`adl\`ag. I was simply remarking that depending on the definition of Poisson process that you encounter, the c\`adl\`ag property may not be explicitly present, but you always have a unique c\`adl\`ag modification for the process and that is what takes the final stamp of Poisson process.

Comment: Almost got it. Just one thing: You've written that $N_t$ only counts the jumps within $[0,t)$. That doesn't make sense to me. If $\omega$ is a realization such that the first jump occurs at $t=\tau_1(\omega)$, then shouldn't we have $N_t(\omega)=1$? I mean, by definition $\tau_1(\omega)=\inf\left\{t>0:\Delta N_t(\omega)>0\right\}$ and if $N_t(\omega)$ would be $0$, then clearly $\Delta N_t(\omega)=0$.

Comment: You are right: $N_{t}$ counts the jumps in $\left[0,t\right]$, otherwise $N_t$ would not be right-continuous -- I committed a mistake with right/left continuity. What we have is that $N_{t-}$ counts the jumps on $\left[0,t\right)$. Somehow I was thinking in this latter process.

Comment: This means that $n^{\star}(\omega)= N_{T}^{(d)}(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$.

Comment: Okay, in order to finish this up: In your answer, you've used my definition of $τ^{(d)}_n$ (I guess). However, meanwhile, it seems more natural to me to define $$τ_n^{(d)}:=\inf\left\{t>τ^{(d)}_{n-1}:ΔN^{(d)}_t>0\right\}.$$ (It's still not clear to me if this new Definition is actually the same as the old one).

Comment: Given this definition and your definition of $n^*$, what can we say about measurability of $n^*$ and why is the Minimum actually attained? All these Things are intuitively trivial, but I'm struggling to prove them rigorously. Even that $τ^{(d)}$ is a stopping time seems to be harder that one might thought at a first glance.

Comment: By the way, did you use at any stage that $Y$ is Markov? It seems like everything would have worked the same way if $Y$ would be any process.

Comment: You asked three questions: (a) If the definition you stated last is equivalent to the one I use for $n^{\star}$; (b) How to show that $n^{\star}$ is a measurable function; (c) why is the minimum in my definition of $n^{\star}$ attained. (c) the minimum is attained (i.e., $n^{\star}<\infty$, almost surely) because within any compact interval, we only have finite many jumps, almost surely (it is a well-known property of Poisson processes); (b) as pointed before, $n^{\star}=N_T^{(d)}$ and thus, measurable; (a) the definition you present above is the definition of the instant of the nth jump,

Comment: $n^{\star}\in\mathbb{N}_0$ that we have in the proof is basically the Poisson $N_T^{(d)}$ restricted to the compact interval $\left[0,T\right]$. We have $n^{\star}$ for the sake of a compact notation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, we did not need Markovianity of $Y$.

Comment: We almost got it, bear with me. Regarding your proof of weak convergence, what's the definition of $\tilde X$? I didn't define this process. It seems to me that you've confused $\overline X^{(d)}$ and $\overline X$ with $\tilde X^{(d)}$ and $\tilde X$. Your "overline" processes are the "tilde" processes from the question, right? And I suppose that $\tilde X^{(d)}$ and $\tilde X$ from your weak convergence proof are new processes whose existence is ensured by the Skorohod coupling.

Comment: Oh, and I might be wrong, but it seems to me that the only reason you've introduced the equivalent complete metric $\rho^\circ$ was to apply the Skorohod couplung theorem. But doesn't this theorem hold for any separable metric space? It should be and so it should be no problem to stick with our previous metric $\rho$. In the same way we could conclude $\rho(\hat X^{(d)},\hat X)\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0$ for some $D([0,\infty))$-valued process $\hat X^{(d)}$ and $D([0,\infty))$-valued random variable $\hat X$ distributed as $X^{(d)}$ and $X$.

Comment: And the last thing I've observed: Is $\mathcal C_{[0,\:\infty)}$ the set of continuous functions $[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$? If so, how do we see that it belongs to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $D([0,\infty))$?

Comment: Regarding your first comment: $\overline{X}^{(d)}$ is your $\bar{X}^{(d)}$; I am not sure where you saw $\overline{X}$ without the upperscript $(d)$; the processes $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}$ and $\widetilde{X}$ are the Skorokhod representations for $X^{(d)}$ and $X$. Regarding your second comment: absolutely, you are right, only separability is required. I decided to invoke this other equivalent metric $\rho^{o}$ simply because Theorem 16.2 in Billingsley is stated with this metric -- even though the Theorem holds for $\rho$ as well -- and

Comment: I thought better to stay consistent with the theorem stated in Billingsley.

Comment: Regarding your last question, of course, this is an important issue as $\mathcal{C}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ is not measurable in the Borel sigma-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}_{+}}$ with the product topology. But, $\mathcal{C}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ is measurable in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ (it is in, fact a closed set). One way to see it is that it is the inverse image of the set $\left\{0\right\}$ by a certain continuous map, see for instance, page 147 in Ethier and Kurtz.

Comment: You've used that if $\rho^\circ(x_n,x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, then $\rho^\circ_T(x_n,x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ for all continuity points $T\ge0$ of $x$. Does the same hold for $\rho$ and $\rho_T$? ([Lemma 9.2 here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~serik/WeakConv/C-space.pdf) seems to be related.)

Comment: Yes, that is what I used -- and that is why I imposed $X$ to have almost sure continuous sample paths, as otherwise, when I look at the Skorokhod representation of this process, $\widetilde{X}$, I would loose control on that, and I need this theorem applied to $\widetilde{X}$. Yes, I realized latter that we can actually have it just in terms of the norm $\rho$, but when I wrote I decided to be consistent with the reference that I was pointing.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim? In Billingsley (Theorem 16.2) it is only given for $\rho^\ast$.

Comment: In Billingsley it is given for $\rho^{o}$ which is what we have in the proof. For $\rho$, I don't have a reference. I think it is actually better to keep it with $\rho^{o}$ (I am not fully confident about having 'if and only if' for the claim with $\rho$, I would have to think about it).

Comment: But, to establish the weak convergence (as we do), whether we use $\rho$ or $\rho^{o}$ is irrelevant, as weak convergence is sensitive only to the underlying topology -- and $\rho$ and $\rho^{o}$ are topologically equivalent. That is why sometimes I (carefully) invoke one or the other.

Comment: Are the metrics $d_\infty$ and $d_\infty^\circ$ defined [here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~serik/WeakConv/C-space.pdf) on page 56 in terms of series the same metrics as they're defined by Ethier/Kurz in terms of integrals? How are these two definitions consistent? I guess on $D([0,T])$ the $d_t$ (or, as we called it $\rho_t$,) are semimetrics and hence the series thing is a way to metrizing the topology ...

Comment: $\rho_t$ is a metric (not a semimetric) for $D_{\left[0,t\right]}$. The series is to induce a metric for $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$. How are these related with Ethier? They should be topologically equivalent (but, I have to look more closely).

Comment: At the end you've shown that $\overline{X}^{(d)}\longrightarrow X$ weakly in $D([0,T])$ for all $T>0$. How exactly do you conclude $\overline{X}^{(d)}\longrightarrow X$ weakly in $D([0,\infty))$? ([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470809/weak-convergence-in-the-skorohod-space-d0-t-forall-t-implies-weak-conv#475011) seems to be related).

Comment: I invoke Skorokhod representation again, which yields $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}$ converging almost surely to $\widetilde{X}$, with respect to the metric $\rho_T^{o}$ in $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$, where $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}\equiv \overline{X}^{(d)}$ and $\widetilde{X}\equiv X$ are equal in distribution. Then, again by 16.2 Billingsley, we get that $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}$ converges almost surely to $\widetilde{X}$ in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ for the metric $\rho^{o}_{\infty}$. But this implies that $X^{(d)}$ converges weakly to $X$ in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$. That is, I do need the 'if and only if'

Comment: of 16.2 Billingsley

Comment: I have not seen the details in the question that you pointed, but it might be an alternative way (alternative to the Skorokhod+16.2) to obtain the last part. Does it follow from this answer that weak convergence in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ implies weak convergence in $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$? If so, then this is an alternative way to establish Lemma 1.

Comment: One correction: this is an alternative way to establish the last step (convergence $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$ for all $T$ implies convergence in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$), not Lemma 1.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. The OP of the other question asks for "convergence in $D([0,T])$ for all $T$ if and only if convergence in $D([0,\infty))$". The answer, if I understand it correctly, is aiming the "only if" part. But I got some doubts regarding its correctness.

Comment: And I've just seen that you've mentioned that there is a typo in $(2)$. I think there is no typo. I've applied the time-shift to $\tilde X^{(d)}$ (which seems to be more natural to me, by the way we've constructed $\lambda$) and you applied it to $X^{(d)}$. It doesn't matter whether a time shift is applied to the first or second argument of the metric, but I think you need to apply the inverse of $\lambda$ if you apply it to $X^{(d)}$.

Comment: Note that $\overline{X}^{(d)}_{\lambda_t^{(d)}}=\overline{X}^{(d)}_t$ and $X^{(d)}_{\lambda^{(d)}_t}=\overline{X}^{(d)}_t$. Thus, where we place the $\lambda$ matters in order to kill the term involving the processes and we just need to control the abscissa-wiggling term. If we place it as $\overline{X}^{(d)}_{\lambda_t^{(d)}}$, then we do not get rid of the second term with the processes as $\overline{X}^{(d)}_{\lambda_t^{(d)}}=\overline{X}^{(d)}_t$.

Comment: Just to be sure: Since there is no $\overline X^{(d)}$ in my question, I guess you mean $\tilde X^{(d)}$ instead. Then, by construction, $\lambda^{(d)}(k/d)=\tau_k^{(d)}$ for all $k\in\left\{0,\ldots,n^\ast\right\}$ and $\lambda^{(d)}(T)=T$. So, $\tilde X^{(d)}_{\lambda^{(d)}(t)}=X^{(d)}_t$ and hence $\rho_T\left(\tilde X^{(d)}_{\lambda^{(d)}(t)},X^{(d)}_t\right)=0$ for all $t\in[0,T]$ which is exactly what we want. Placing the shift at $X^{(d)}=Y^{(d)}\circ\lfloor d\;\cdot\;\rfloor$ instead wouldn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, $\overline{X}^{(d)}$ stands for your $\tilde{X}^{(d)}$. Absolutely, you are correct: $\tilde{X}^{(d)}_{\lambda^{(d)}(t)}=X^{(d)}_t$. Let me correct this on the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there is a major issue with your proof of Theorem 1: You've shown that $\mathbb{P}\left(\displaystyle\sup_{t\in\left[0,T\right]}\left|\lambda_{t}^{(d)}-t\right|>\epsilon\right)\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0$, but since we only know that $\rho_T\left(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)}\right)\leq\displaystyle\sup_{t\in\left[0,T\right]}\left|\lambda_{t}^{(d)}-t\right|$ we cannot conclude $\mathbb{P}\left(\rho_T\left(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)}\right)>\epsilon\right)\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0$ from that. Hopefully, I'm missing something crucial.

Comment: No, it is correct (this was in, fact something I looked at by the time I wrote it): We have that (I will proceed slowly): $\rho(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)})\leq \left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}_t-{\sf id}\right|\right|$. This implies that: $\rho(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)})>\epsilon \Rightarrow \left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}_t-{\sf id}\right|\right|>\epsilon$. This further implies that $\left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,\rho(\overline{X}^{(d)}(\omega),X^{(d)}(\omega))>\epsilon\right\}$ $\subset$ $\left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, \left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}_t(\omega) - {\sf id}\right|\right|>\epsilon\right\}$

Comment: Therefore, $\mathbb{P}\left(\rho(\overline{X}^{(d)},X^{(d)})>\epsilon\right)\leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\left|\lambda^{(d)}-{\sf id}\right|\right|>\epsilon\right)\longrightarrow 0$

Comment: I will include this in the answer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Sure, maybe it was too late for me. I think we've got it now! I don't want to overstrain your help, but do you've got any idea about this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140066/47771?

Comment: Let me think about it.

Comment: Thank you in advance. There is one unresolved technical issue in your proof of Lemma 1. At the end, you invoke the Skorohod coupling for $\left(\tilde X^{(d)}_t\right)_{t\in[0,\:T]}\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ weakly in $D([0,T]$ for fixed $T>0$. But this yields processes $\left(Z^{(d,\:T)}_t\right)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ and $(Z^{(T)}_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ distributed as $\left(\tilde X^{(d)}_t\right)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ and $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ converging almost surely, but they depend on $T$.

Comment: I think we need to show that $\left(Z^{(d,\:T')}_t\right)_{t\in[0,\:T]}=\left(Z^{(d,\:T)}_t\right)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ almost surely for all $T'\ge T\ge0$ and $(Z^{(T')}_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}=(Z^{(T)}_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ almost surely for all $T'\ge T\ge0$ for your conclusion to be valid.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this arises in the very last step where we would like to conclude weak convergence in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ from weak convergence in $D_{\left[0,T\right)}$ for all $T$. Here, we need rather to invoke [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470809/weak-convergence-in-the-skorohod-space-d0-t-forall-t-implies-weak-conv#475011). I will check this soon and update accordingly.

Comment: This is a possibility to finish the last step: let $\overline{X}^{(d)}\rightarrow X$ weakly in $D_{\left[0,T\right]}$ for all $T>0$. Then, $\overline{X}^{(d)}\rightarrow X$ weakly in $D_{\left[i,i+1\right]}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Let $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}_{\left[i,i+1\right)}$ (respectively, $\widetilde{X}_{\left[i,i+1\right)}$) be the Skorokhod representation of $\overline{X}^{(d)}_{\left[i,i+1\right)}$ (respectively, $X_{\left[i,i+1\right)}$) so that $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}_{\left[i,i+1\right)}$ converges almost surely to $\widetilde{X}_{\left[i,i+1\right)}$ (to be continued)

Comment: For each $\omega\in\Omega$ choose $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}(\cdot,\omega)\in D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ so that $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}(t,\omega)=\widetilde{X}^{(d)}_{\left[i,i+1\right)}(t,\omega)$, if $i \leq t<i+1$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$. The existence of such $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}$ is granted by the axiom of choice. Do the same construction to define $\widetilde{X}(\cdot,\omega)$. This construction yields $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}\equiv \overline{X}^{(d)}$ and $\widetilde{X}\equiv X$ in distribution in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ (to be continued)

Comment: Now, from 16.2 Billingsley, we have that $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}$ converges almost surely to $\widetilde{X}$ in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$. And weak convergence $\overline{X}^{(d)}\rightarrow X$ in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ follows. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not convinced. I think we replaced one vague argument by another. No one keeps us from defining $\tilde X^{(d)}$ (unfortunately our notation is a bit off, since there are multiple $\tilde X^{(d)}$'s around - this one is supposed to be the one from your second to last comment) in the way you did. It is well-defined in a functional sense. But there is an argument missing why this $\tilde X^{(d)}$ has the same distribution as $X^{(d)}$.

Comment: And I think it still boils down to show that we are allowed to choose the $Z^{(d,\:T)}$ (from my last comment) in such a way that $Z^{(d,\:T)}$ and $\left(Z^{(d,\:T')}_t\right)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ are indistinguishable for all $T'\ge T\ge0$. Actually, I would be surprised if this is not possible. Maybe one needs to dive into the proof of the Skorohod coupling. Or we need to think about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470809/47771) agian. (off-topic: Did you had a chance to think about the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140066/47771)?)

Comment: The idea was to build one single representation $\widetilde{X}$ in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ that when restricted to $\left[i,i+1\right)$ coincides with $\widetilde{X}_{\left[i,i+1\right)}$. I think everything is in place, but I have to check the details. (Not yet, I'll think about it soon.)

Comment: Not seriously yet, I will check it this weekend.

Comment: I don't want to hurry you. You've helped me a lot so far. But this problem is really bothering me. I got your idea, but I don't think that it resolves the aforementioned problem. Do you still think it holds? (What do you think about the answer to the other question? I think the author used the claim he's trying to prove in his argument ...

Comment: I think what we have in one of my last comments resolves: we are constructing a random $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}\,:\,\Omega\times \mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ in a way that at each interval $\left[i,i+1\right)$ it is given by the Skorokhod representation $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}$ on $D_{\left[i,i+1\right)}$ -- the same for $\widetilde{X}$ on $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$. Now, we just need to guarantee that everything is in place: (to be continued)

Comment: In particular, that the constructed $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}$ and $\widetilde{X}$ in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$ are equal in distribution to $\overline{X}^{(d)}$ and $\overline{X}$. We know that at each interval $\left[i,i+1\right)$ they are, but does this imply that they are in $\left[0,\infty\right)$. Further, with this construction, is there any pitfall with the convergence in $D_{\left[0,\infty\right)}$? I think we have everything in place, but one needs to make sure the formalism is Ok -- which I will as soon as possible. (to be continued)

Comment: Regarding the other question, I could not follow all the details so far -- I am still thinking in view of the Skorokhod representation point of view. Perhaps, they had something in mind that I am missing -- but, I will check it again.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Let me get back to you tomorrow (I am trying to make sure that what I have is Ok.).

Comment: (If we cannot resolve the remaining issues, we might think once again about what Kallenberg wrote in his proof. He said that the claim would follow from Theorem 4.28 together with the strong law of large numbers for $N$. We didn't use the latter so far; and actually I can't see where it could be used.)

Comment: (I think the Skorokhod representation root works, but we need to have this neat. I will let you know what we have in a bit. I think, regardless, it is a good exercise to understand what Kallenberg's had in mind -- does he mean weak convergence in $D[0,\infty)$ or $D[0,T]$? It is also very surprising that one cannot find this result (i.e., weak convergence for all $D[0,T]$ implies weak convergence in $D[0,\infty)$) in the literature.)

Comment: The only technical issue is in the very last step: we have that ($\star$)$\overline{X}^{(d)}\longrightarrow \overline{X}$ weakly in $D[0,T]$ for any $T$, and from this, we would like to conclude that ($\star \star$) $\overline{X}^{(d)}\longrightarrow \overline{X}$ weakly in $D[0,\infty)$. Indeed, ($\star$) implies: i) $\overline{X}^{(d)} 1_{[i,i+1)}\rightarrow \overline{X} 1_{[i,i+1)}$ weakly in $D_{[i,i+1)}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}\cup \left\{0\right\}$; (to be continued)

Comment: ii) From the Skorokhod Representation Theorem, there exists $\widetilde{X}^{(i,d)}\equiv\overline{X}^{(d)} 1_{[i,i+1)}$ and $\widetilde{X}^{(i)}\equiv\overline{X} 1_{[i,i+1)}$, where $\equiv$ means 'equal in distribution', with $\widetilde{X}^{(i,d)}\rightarrow \widetilde{X}^{(i)}$, almost surely for all $i$; iii) define $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}\,:\,\Omega \times \mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}(\omega,t)=\widetilde{X}^{(i,d)}(\omega,t)$ when $t\in [i,i+1)$; (to be continued)

Comment: iv) define $\widetilde{X}\,:\,\Omega \times \mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\widetilde{X}(\omega,t)=\widetilde{X}^{(i)}(\omega,t)$ when $t\in [i,i+1)$; v) from Theorem 16.2 in Billingsley, we have that $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}\rightarrow\widetilde{X}$ almost surely; vi) we have that $\widetilde{X}^{(d)}\equiv \overline{X}^{(d)}$ and $\widetilde{X}\equiv \overline{X}$ in $D_{[0,\infty)}$; vii) therefore, $\overline{X}^{(d)}\rightarrow \overline{X}$ weakly in $D_{[0,\infty)}$.

Comment: What steps are not clear and you would like to discuss more?

Comment: Thank you, once again, for your comments. Let me note that I've noticed that we may invoke Slutsky's theorem instead of Theorem 4.28 to obtain (in a maybe easier way) $\tilde X^{(d)}\to X$ weakly in $D([0,T])$ from $X^{(d)}\to X$ weakly in $D([0,T])$. Now, I see a minor and a major issue with your construction. The minor issue is, that I think you need to use compact intervals $[i,i+1]$ (instead of the half-open intervals $[i,i+1)$), since I'm not sure whether or not all of the properties of the Skorohod metric we're using still hold when the underlying time interval is not compact.

Comment: The major issue is that the Skorohod representation theorem (used in a black box fashion) does only yield that your $\tilde X^{(i,\:d)}$ and $\tilde X^{(i)}$ exist on probability spaces $(\tilde\Omega^{(i)},\tilde{\mathcal A}^{(i)},\tilde{\text P}^{(i)})$ depending on $i$. So, you're definition of $\tilde X^{(d)}$ is broken (since you define it on a set $\Omega$ and it seems like you're implicitly assuming that $\tilde\Omega^{(i)}=\Omega$).

Comment: If I could distract you for a second from this problem, could you take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3164232/47771)? In Lemma 2.1 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoap/1034625254) it is implicit in the claim that $(1)$ holds in proability. To be precise, the authors claim that $$\operatorname P\left[\left|-\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^ng''(X_i)-I\right|<n^{-1/8}\right]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$$ as long as $X\sim\pi_n$

Comment: (their $\pi_n$ is the measure with density $x\mapsto\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i)$ wrt Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$). This would imply that $\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^ng''(X_i)\to-I$ in probability, while the weak law of large numbers should imply that the sum converges to $\int f''(x)\:{\rm d}x-I$. This is a celebrated paper and the result is heavily used in practice. So, I'm highly confused what I'm missing.

Comment: I'll get back to you on our previous discussion and the new question in a couple of days.

Comment: I won't be able to go over it this weekend, but I will get back to it by the end of this next week. Thanks.

Comment: If we know that the fdds of a sequence of càdlàg processes converge weakly to a *continuous* process, is there some easy criterion for the weak converge (in the Skorohod topology) available? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327701/if-xn-is-a-sequence-of-c%c3%a0dl%c3%a0g-processes-whose-fdds-converge-to-a-continous-pr

Comment: Quite busy in here, I will get back when things clear out. Looking quickly at your last question (the one on fdds implying weak convergence), this is not true in general. In fact, you need to have some control on the oscillations (or tightness as you pointed). You have, for instance, Arzela-Ascoli theorem in [Jacod](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540439325). Other references that are relevant: [Aldous1](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176995579) and [Aldous2](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176991417).

Comment: Isn't Theorem 16.7 in Billingsley what we need?

Comment: Just wanted to ask if you got something new?

Comment: I have not yet, but I will return soon so we can update it.

Comment: This left a bit out of my focus. Do you think we find a solution some day? ;)

Comment: I did not forget. Regarding a solution, of course! I think we have it already, it is just about piecing everything together. I will work on it now in August (vacation!).

Comment: Thanks for the response!