# Random time change for a Poisson process and convergence with respect to the Skorohod topology

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, poisson-process, skorohod-space

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $\left(Y^{(n)}_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a time-homogeneous Markov chain on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$X^{(n)}_t=Y^{(n)}_{\lfloor nt\rfloor}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,1]$$
- $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Poisson process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with intensity $1$ independent of $Y^{(n)}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $$Z^{(n)}_t:=\begin{cases}Y^{(n)}_{N_{nt}}&\text{for }t\in[0,1)\\ Z^{(n)}_{1-}\end{cases}$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$

Now, let $\tau_0:=0$, $$\tau_k:=\inf\left\{t>\tau_{k-1}:\Delta N_t=1\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$ as well as $$\tau^{(n)}_k:=\frac{\tau_k}n\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$ and $$\lambda^{(n)}_t:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1_{\left[\frac kn,\:\frac{k+1}n\right)}(t)\left(\tau^{(n)}_k+(nt-k)\left(\tau^{(n)}_{k+1}-\tau^{(n)}_k\right)\right)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

> How can we show that $$\sup_{t\ge0}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|=\sup_{t\in[0,\:1)}\left|\frac{N_{nt}}n-t\right|\tag1$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$? (**I'm unsure whether there isn't an error in the domain of one of the suprema.** I could imagine that the left should be taken only over $[0,1)$ or the right actually over $[0,\infty)$.)

I've read that we obtain claim by noting that $N_{nt}=\lfloor n\frac{N_{nt}}n\rfloor$ for all $t\ge0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, but while that's trivially true, I don't see how we can make use of it.

Moreover, I've read that the supremum is attained at one of the jump times (I guess the jump times of $X^{(n)}$, i.e. $\frac kn$ for $k\in\mathbb N$, are meant), but I don't know why.

However, we may observe the following: Let $t\in\left[\frac kn,\frac{k+1}n\right)$. Then, there is an $\alpha\in[0,1)$ with $$t=\frac{k+\alpha}n$$ and hence $$\lambda^{(n)}_t-t=\left(\tau^{(n)}_k-\frac kn\right)+\left(\tau^{(n)}_{k+1}-\tau^{(n)}_k\right)\alpha.\tag2$$ Since this is linear in $\alpha$, the supremum of $(2)$ is attained for $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=1$. Thus, we should obtain $$\sup_{t\ge0}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|=\sup_{k\in\mathbb N_0}\left|\tau^{(n)}_k-\frac kn\right|=\frac1n\sup_{k\in\mathbb N_0}\left|\tau_k-k\right|\tag3.$$ Maybe we need to use $k=N_{\tau_k}$ almost surely such that $$\sup_{t\ge0}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|=\sup_{k\in\mathbb N_0}\left|\frac{N_{n\tau^{(n)}_k}}n-\tau^{(n)}_k\right|\tag4\;\;\;\text{almost surely}.$$ Now, clearly, $\left\{N_{n\tau^{(n)}_k(\omega)}(\omega):k\in\mathbb N_0\right\}=\left\{N_{\tau_k(\omega)}(\omega):k\in\mathbb N_0\right\}=\left\{N_t(\omega):t\ge0\right\}$, but this still doesn't yield $(1)$. However, it yields $$\left[\tau^{(n)}_k,\tau^{(n)}_{k+1}\right)\ni t\mapsto\frac{N_{nt}}n-t=k-t$$ which clearly attains its supremum at $t=\tau^{(n)}_k$ or $t=\tau^{(n)}_{k+1}$.

We may note that $\left(\frac{N_{nt}}n-t\right)_{t\ge0}$ is a martingale, but I'm not sure if we need this fact here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New edit.** An update has been introduced to highlight that equation (1) as stated does not hold unless the domain of the $\sup$ in both sides of the equation is $\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

---

Maybe I am missing something, but you have actually done everything. We have,

$\sup_{t\geq 0}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0} \left|\tau_k-k\right|$ (this is your equation (3))

$\sup_{t\geq 0} \left|\frac{N_{nt}}{n}-t\right|=\sup_{t\geq 0} \left|\frac{N_{nt}-nt}{n}\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{t\geq 0} \left|N_{nt}-nt\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0} \left|N_{\tau_k}-\tau_k\right|$ (as before, without loss of optimality, we can restrict the domain to the jump moments of the Poisson process $N_t$, hence the last equality.)

As you pointed $N_{\tau_k}=k$, and the identity $\sup_{t\geq 0} \left|\frac{N_{nt}}{n}-t\right|=\sup_{t\geq 0}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|$ holds.

**Remark.** Identity (1) does not hold with the domains $t\geq 0$ on the left hand side and $t\in \left[\left.0,1\right)\right.$ on the right hand side. In fact, in this case $\sup_{t\in \left[\left.0,1\right)\right.} \left|\frac{N_{nt}}{n}-t\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{k\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N_n\right\}}\left|\tau_k-k\right|\vee \left|n-N_n\right|$ and we have that $\sup_{k\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N_n\right\}}\left|\tau_k-k\right|\vee \left|n-N_n\right|<\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0}\left|\tau_k-k\right|$ with positive probability, in particular, the strict inequality holds for all realizations $\omega\in\Omega$ so that $\tau_1(\omega)>n+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ -- which holds with positive probability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I've mistakenly started the bounty on the wrong question ... However, rethinking about the question, where in the argumentaiton/construction did we use that $Z_t^{(n)}$ is only equal to $Y^{(n)}_{N_{nt}}$ for $t\in[0,1)$? In other words: Does the identity still hold if we define $Z_t^{(n)}:=Y^{(n)}_{N_{nt}}$ for all $t\ge0$?

Comment: I cannot see how the processes $Z,Y$ and $X$ are relevant at all as far as establishing the identity (1): the relevant processes for this identity are $\lambda^{(n)}_t$ and $N_t$. The process $\lambda^{(n)}_t$ is built upon the Poisson jumps (and does not involve any of these other processes). Maybe your question relates with the possibility of having $t\in\left[\left.0,1\right)\right.$ in the domain of the sup in the right hand side of (1). From the second equation in the answer above, if we insist on this restriction, we loose optimality and in this case, we have (to be continued)

Comment: $\sup_{t\in\left[\left.0,1\right)\right.}\left|\frac{N_{nt}}{n}-t\right| < \sup_{t\geq 0}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|$ with positive probability, in particular, we have strict inequality for all realizations $\omega\in\Omega$ where $\tau_1(\omega)>n+\epsilon$, which is a set of positive probability. But, let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Actually, [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019020/convergence-of-discrete-time-markov-chain-to-feller-processes) describes more precisely what I've got in mind. Maybe you can take a look. However, so, you're saying that instead of $(1)$ it holds $\sup_{t\ge0}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|=\sup_{t\ge0}\left|\frac{N_{nt}}n-t\right|$, right? Maybe you should point that out in your answer, since currently it reads like you're saying that $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4656.pdf) too. $(1)$ is $(4.12)$ (on page 9) therein. The author states that "the steps after $n-1\wedge N_{n-}$ can not be compensated by a time transformation", but I guess that's only the case when $Z^{(n)}_t$ is defined as in this question here. It's not completely clear to me how his process $Z^{(n)}_t$ is defined for $t>1$.

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestions. Let me check more closely your other question (and the paper you pointed).

Comment: How exactly do you obtain $\sup_{t\in \left[\left.0,T\right)\right.}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{k\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N_{Tn}\right\}}\left|\tau_k-k\right|\vee \left|Tn-N_{Tn}\right|$?

Comment: What I wrote in Remark 2 is inaccurate. The reasoning was that we need to not only observe the jump moments, but also the final moment $T$. In fact, while $\sup_{t\in\left[\left.0,T\right)\right.}\left|\frac{N_{tn}}{n}-t\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{k\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N_{Tn}\right\}}\left|\tau_k-k\right|\vee \left|Tn-N_{Tn}\right|$, the other term $\sup_{t\in\left[\left.0,T\right)\right.}\left|\lambda_t^{(n)}-t\right|$ is not equal to this. I will simply remove Remark 2. Note that this does not compromise your other question (you can check my answer when possible).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how we obtain $\sup_{t\in \left[\left.0,T\right)\right.}\left|\lambda^{(n)}_t-t\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{k\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N_{Tn}\right\}}\left|\tau_k-k\right|\vee \left|Tn-N_{Tn}\right|$ (if it's not too much effort you)?

Comment: This identity that you wrote does not hold (that is why I decided to remove my previous remark from the answer). What holds is: $\sup_{t\in\left[\left.0,T\right)\right.}\left|\frac{N_{tn}}{n}-t\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{k\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N_{Tn}\right\}}\left|\tau_k-k\right|\vee \left|Tn-N_{Tn}\right|$. This is because the $\sup$ can be restricted to the jumps of the Poisson process -- this in turn is because from a jump to the next, the gap $\left|\frac{N_{tn}}{n}-t\right|$ is nondecreasing as inbetween jumps the Poisson is constant. When the interval is bounded, (to be continued)

Comment: Now, when the interval is bounded, i.e., $T<\infty$, then you have an interval $\left[\left.\tau_{N_{Tn}},T\right)\right.$ where the gap $\left|\frac{N_{tn}}{n}-t\right|$ increases up until the time $T$. In other words, one has to account for the gap at the time $T$, i.e., $\left|\frac{N_{Tn}}{n}-T\right|$ and that is why the extra term appears. Now, let me follow-up slowly: (to be continued)

Comment: $\sup_{t\in\left[\left.0,T\right)\right.}\left|\frac{N_{tn}}{n}-t\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{t\in\left[\left.0,T\right)\right.}\left|N_{tn}-tn\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{\left\{t=\tau_0^{(n)},\tau_1^{(n)},\ldots,\tau^{(n)}_{N_{Tn}},T\right\}}\left|N_{tn}-tn\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{\left\{k=0,1,\ldots,N_{Tn}\right\}}\left|N_{\tau_k}-\tau_k\right|\vee\left|N_{Tn}-Tn\right|=\frac{1}{n}\sup_{\left\{k=0,1,\ldots,N_{Tn}\right\}}\left|k-\tau_k\right|\vee\left|N_{Tn}-Tn\right|$.

Comment: If something is not clear, let me know.